# Чем отличается QTextDocument от QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

Чем отличается класс QTextDocument от QTextEdit ? И какой из них в каких случаях нужно использовать?

Comment: [описание из официальной документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#details)

Comment: QTextEdit  - графический элемент (виджет). QTextDocument  - объектная модель текстового документа, с разбивкой на параграфы, стили и т.д. (деталь реализации этого widget-а). Учитывая что это совсем разные сущности  - вопрос "чем отличается" - непонятен.

Answer (score 1):

QTextDocument - это контейнер для структурированных документов с форматированным текстом, который обеспечивает поддержку стилизованного текста и различных типов элементов документа, таких как списки, таблицы, фреймы и изображения. Они могут быть созданы для использования в QTextEdit или использоваться независимо.

QTextEdit - это расширенный WYSIWYG viewer/editor, поддерживает форматирование форматированного текста с использованием тегов HTML. Он оптимизирован для обработки больших документов и быстрого реагирования на вводимые пользователем данные.

Также, стоит отметить, что QTextDocument предоставляется модулем gui, а QTextEdit это виджет.